# How to control the fan speed in old HP laptop running Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, fan, hp

I want to control my laptops fan speed so that fan can nicely cool down.
My laptop is HP G62.
I tried some suggestions that doesn't seem to work.

I didn't tried it on windows. Now I have Ubuntu only. I tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed

But `sudo pwmconfig` says 
`/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed` and also  there is no /etc/fancontrol file in the system too.

Since the OS control the fan speed if the temperature is too high I thought I could set threshold temperature to another low temperature.

Comment: On some laptops, you can't control fan speed at all. Do you know if you can control it in windows? Also please specify what you tried.

Comment: I didn't tried it on windows. Now I have Ubuntu  only.
I tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed
But sudo pwmconfig says
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
and there is no /etc/fancontrol file in the system too.

Comment: Since the OS control the fan speed if the temperature is too high
I thought I could set threshold temperature to another  low temperature.

Comment: Thanks. I have done editing the question.

Comment: To fix the no pwn-capable sensor modules found you could relax the kernel acpi check `acpi_enforce_resources=lax`. https://iandw.net/2014/10/12/fancontrol-under-ubuntu-14-04-resolving-usrsbinpwmconfig-there-are-no-pwm-capable-sensor-modules-installed/

Comment: tried `acpi_enforce_resources=lax`  in grub . It  didn't add any modules